# jQuery plugin that accepts and returns value using val() method

Tags: jquery-plugins

Does anyone knows how to create a jQuery plugin that will react to the call to val() method?

Here's the scenario:

1. Take a set of DIVs using jQuery selector and apply a plugin on them (let's say the plugin is called "mytest".
2. Using the val() method on the same set of DIVs I'd like to set them some properties.

What's the proper way to do this sort of things?

```
$.fn.example = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var edits = $("<input type='text'/><input type='text' />");
        $(this).html(edits);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#example").example();
    $("#example").val("value1 value2");
    window.alert($("#example").val());
});
```

In this case the first edit should have the value "value1" and the second edit the value "value2". And v.v. by calling the "val()" method I'd like to get the string "value1 value2" back.

Best regards,
Matthias

Comment: You mean if you do this $('.mydivs').mytest().val('...'); you want the val method of only those divs to be overridden to something else?

Comment: yes. the truth of the matter is that the div is greatly extended with some controls and the val() method should return a string representing the actual value of those controls. It would be great if it'd could work both ways (get/set).

Comment: I'd like to help you but you need to add more details to your question. Give an example of the expected behaviour.

Comment: And why does it have to be through the val() function? Why not just do the setting and getting through mytest()?

Comment: I'll post an example in a few moments.
And btw - it doesn't have to be val() - it could be anything. I just thought that it'd nicely combine with the rest of the API (where you can get a value of an edit field with val())

Comment: Overriding a native jQuery function to do something it doesn't is bad practice. It would be best to have it named something else. Also, as far as the example, so you would want this function to return the values of all the inputs inside the element separated by spaces when called without an argument, and set the values of all the elements inside the element when called with an argument?

Comment: Well Paolo, one might agree if using val to retrieve the value of a component is not what val actually does.
And yes, creating an extra function to get/set the value would'd be one possible way. However if I'm to have more than one custom control it'd be kind of difficult to remember all the functions and to which type of controls they apply.

Comment: You could still have a single separate function for it. I am not really sure what your "controls" are all about but you could mark them with a class and do whatever you want a certain control to do inside the function depending on what class it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized that by using additional methods and then calling them using

```
$("...").pluginname("methodname", ..parameters..);
```

syntax. It works exactly like other plugins so I guess that's the right way to go.
In the case of the example above the code would look like this:

```
$.widget("ui.example", {
    _init: function() {
    }
});

$.extend($.ui.example, {
    version: "1.7.1",
    defaults: {
        value: ""
    }
});
```

And then the usage would be:

```
$("#example").example("option", "value", "value1 value2");
var value = $("#example").example("option", "value");
window.alert(value);
```